# tmux - get pwd of another pane in a bash script?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, tmux, bash-scripting

Is there anyway to find out information about the current working directory of any pane from within a tmux session?

I'd like to write a bash script that changes the directory of the current pane to the directory of another pane, even if that pane has a program or script already running in it.

The way I'd like to do it is to navigate to pane 1, then I'd goto pane 2, hit a hot key and pane 2 would now change to the same pwd as pane 1.

Comment: Does this work: `tmux display-message -p -F "#{pane_current_path}" -t0`?

Comment: yeah that does seem to work... totally add that as an answer!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
tmux display-message -p -F "#{pane_current_path}" -t0
```

Comment: sweet! this totally worked... and for what it's worth, here's the simple script I put together to allow me to switch the current panes directory to the directory of the last accessed pane. `tmux last-pane; DIR=$(tmux display-message -p -F "#{pane_current_path}"); tmux last-pane; cd $DIR`, and this can be bound in your `~/.tmux.conf` using `bind f run "tmux_last_dir"` where `tmux_last_dir` contains the script mentioned before. This would allow you to hit `TMUX_PREFIX + f` to switch your current pane's folder using the script.

Comment: I'm glad that you like it :) This is what SE is for!

Comment: yeah I spent about an hour playing around with it, and didn't know about the `display-message` command, which I somehow missed in the man page. That's going to be super useful in itself.... Thanks again!

Comment: You are actually saving my life!

Comment: This works perfectly. It was just what I was looking for! I activate the pane, detach and if I execute this I get that current path.

Comment: That was really helpful! Thanks!